Failed while building a JavaFX project on macOS
I had a problem when I tried to build my first JavaFX project. The structure of my project folder is
- HelloFX
    - HelloWorld.class
    - HelloWorld.java
    - lib
        - javafx.controls.jar
        - ... ( all standard javafx files downloaded from the official website )

And the content of HelloWorld.java is
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloWorld extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start( Stage primaryStage ) {
        Label label = new Label( "Hello, JavaFX!" );
        Scene scene = new Scene( label, 200, 100 );
        primaryStage.setScene( scene );
        primaryStage.setTitle( "JavaFX Hello World" );
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        launch( args );
    }
}

My laptop is MacBook Pro, 13-inch, 2020, Graphics: Intel Iris Plus Graphics 1536 MB, Processor: 16 GB 3733 MHz LPDDR4X. The system is macOS Ventura, version 13.5.2. The version of JavaFX is 22 for x64, and OpenJDK is 21.0.2.
I tried to compile the file using
javac --module-path ./lib --add-modules javafx.controls HelloWorld.java

And it worked. I expected the project would be build successfully and a window would pop upon my terminal says "Hello JavaFX!". But as I tried
java --module-path ./lib --add-modules javafx.controls HelloWorld

The output turned to be
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:283)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:253)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:263)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:290)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:162)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:651)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1135)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:118)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1135)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:275)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:290)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:162)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:651)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    ... 2 more

Is there anything wrong with my computer? And how can I solve this problem and successfully build up my project?

What are "all standard javafx files downloaded from the official website"?  Probably you are missing the native code.  Follow getting started instructions at openjfx.io.

If you downloaded JavaFX from Gluon (i.e., you downloaded the JavaFX SDK), then there should be JAR files in the <sdk>/lib directory and native libraries in the <sdk>/bin directory. Both the JAR files and the native libraries are required to run a JavaFX application. A "no toolkit found" error typically means the appropriate native libraries are missing/cannot be found.
